# MySQL and Scheduled Updates by User Preference?

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, perl, scheduling

I'm developing an application that

- stores an e-mail address (to a user) in a table.
- stores the number of days the user would like to stay in the table.
- takes the user off the table when the number of days is up.

I don't really know how to approach this, so here are my questions:

1. Each second, do I have the application check through every table entry for the time that's currently stored in, let's say, the `time_left` column?
2. Wouldn't (1) be inefficient if I'm expecting a significant number (10,000+) users?
3. If not (2), what's the best algorithm to implement for such a task?
4. What's the name of what I'm trying to do here?  I'd like to do some more research on it before and while I'm writing the script, so I need a good search query to start with.

I plan on writing this script in Perl, although I'm open to suggestions with regards to language choice, frameworks, etc... I'm actually new to web development (both on the back-end and front-end), so I'd appreciate it if you could advise me precisely.

Thank you!

*after posting, [Topener](https://stackoverflow.com/users/249710/topener) asked a valid question:

> Why would you store users if they won't get requested?

Assume the user is just sitting in the database.

Let's say I'm using the user's e-mail address every 5 minutes from the time the user was added to the database (so if the user's entry was born at 2:00PM-October 18, the user would be accessed at 2:05, 2:10, etc...).

If the user decides that they want out of the database in 10 days, that means their entry is being accessed normally (every 5 minutes from 2:00PM-October 18) until 2:00PM-October 28.

So to clarify, based on this situation:

**The system would have to constantly compare the current time with the user's expiration date, wouldn't it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a separate program/script which makes the delete query on a set interval. If you are on a Linux machine you can create a cron job to do it. Doing it every second may become very resource intensive for slower machines and larger tables, but I don't believe that will become an issue for a simple delete query.

Answer (score 2):

you should not store the time_left variable, bt you should store vaildTo. This way, whenever the user is requested from the database, you can check if it is valid.

If not, then do whatever you want with it.

This approach wont let you make any cronjobs, or will cost you extramload.

Comment: Why would the user be requested, given the scenario I described?  And that still doesn't tell me WHEN or how I should check for when the user is supposed to be removed from the database.

Comment: why would you store users if they won't get requested? Furthermore, I hope you can compare 2 dates?

Comment: answer to that, yes it would. But still this makes more sense than running something every second/minute

Comment: but I'd have to check every second/minute/(or any other interval) to see which users are next in the cycle for expiration -- and by "cycle" in this context, I mean one sift through the entire database to compare the two values in question.

Answer (score 1):

Hey Mr_spock I like the above answer from Topener. Instead of storing a number of days the user would like to be valid, store the day the user would like to be be removed.

Adding a field like validToDate, which would be a DATETIME field type, you can do a query like

*delete from tablename where validToDate <= NOW()*

where

- the *italicized* text is a SQL query
- tablename is the name of the table in question
- NOW() is a valid sql function that returns the current DATETIME
- validToDate is a field of type DATETIME

This has what ever efficiency SQL server promises, I think it is fairly good.